# How to deal with gregorian and julian dates form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, date

I'm kinda new to Javascript.

My problem is the following : I have to implement a form that is generated by a js file, by taking the url and paste it inside my HTML. I have a date input, and I need to verify if the date is right, wether it is dd/mm/aaaa or mm/dd/aaaa.

If possible, without using regExp. I already made this function out of StackOverflow RegExp :

```
    function validateDateRegExp(field){
  var date=field.value;
  var regExp1 = /^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[\s\.\-\/](0[13578]|1[02])[\s\.\-\/]((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)[\s\.\-\/](0[13456789]|1[012])[\s\.\-\/]((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])[\s\.\-\/]02[\s\.\-\/]((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29[\s\.\-\/]02[\s\.\-\/]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/;
  var regExp2 = /^((\d{2}(([02468][048])|([13579][26]))[\-\/\s]?((((0?[13578])|(1[02]))[\-\/\s]?((0?[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[01])))|(((0?[469])|(11))[\-\/\s]?((0?[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(30)))|(0?2[\-\/\s]?((0?[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])))))|(\d{2}(([02468][1235679])|([13579][01345789]))[\-\/\s]?((((0?[13578])|(1[02]))[\-\/\s]?((0?[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[01])))|(((0?[469])|(11))[\-\/\s]?((0?[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(30)))|(0?2[\-\/\s]?((0?[1-9])|(1[0-9])|(2[0-8]))))))(\s(((0?[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\:([0-5][0-9])((\s)|(\:([0-5][0-9])\s))([AM|PM|am|pm]{2,2})))?$/;
  if(!(regExp1.test(date)||regExp2.test(date))){
    alert(date);
    document.getElementById('fld_CS_BuyingDate').value="";
  }
}
```

I'm looking for a solution since 2 days, but the answers are not clear, or the problem is not the same.

Does anyone have any idea on how I could work that out ?

Thanks for the future answers

Comment: You might want to check out a JS Lib called Moment.js - http://momentjs.com/

Comment: It is only possible to tell between d/m/y and m/d/y formats if m or d are greater than 12 and the year is greater than 31.  You should never guess the format, it should be given to the parser (and don't use *Date* or *Date.parse* for that as they don't accept a format).